# Me imprime datos o valores basura en la estructura vector

Tags: c++, array, estructuras, imprimir

Es que tengo una estructura creada, y hago un vector de estructuras, para registrar varios libros con el mismo tipo de información, pero a la hora de imprimir los valores me imprime valores basura, específicamente en estos vectores char autor[], titulo[], editorial[];

y pues no se como inicializarlas ya que al inicializarlas toca establecerles un tamaño, y yo no quiero hacer eso, ya que en una parte de código el tamaño del vector estructura se establece automáticamente con lo que digite el usuario.

acá les dejo mi código:
https://github.com/kaslack/devCppProblemaBiblioteca/blob/main/Biblioteca.cpp

Comment: Pon en la pregunta el código relevante.

Answer (score -1):

Kevin

Probablemente quieras reconsiderar tu estructura de datos, los arrays en C++ son estructuras previamente definidas en longitud, cuando te sales del espacio reservado vas a encontrar datos de otras variables.

**SOLUCION**

Los arrays no se pueden modificar en tamaño, la estructura que buscas es una **lista** (linked lists). Las listas son estructuras que **guardan la información** (el dato) **y la localización del siguiente dato**, así generas una cadena que esta físicamente separada pero que "sabe" donde está el siguiente elemento.

[image: Linked List Diagram]

Revisa el tema de punteros de memoria, es importante que entiendas como funcionan.

Otra opción es generar un nuevo arreglo y copiar los elementos existentes en el viejo, pero eso te consumirá más procesos y memoria.

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones me sirvieron, voy a mirar lo de los punteros.